# Why does that both lists are modified?

Tags: python, list, del

So I'm trying to create a back up of a list but when I want to modify the backup variable, both are being modified.

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
b = a
del a[-1]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
```

What can I do so my output looks like this:

```
[[1, 2],[1, 2]
[[1, 2]
```

Comment: There is only one list, with two references to it.

Comment: `b = a.copy()`.

Comment: For this use case `copy` is enough. But you need [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) if you do something like `a[0][0] = 42`.

Comment: For reference: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).